# Convert Date in to custom format in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a Date format like this

```
 2014-11-18T20:50:01.462Z
```

I need to convert to the custom format like "20:50 2014-18-11" using Javascript date function

I need result like

```
20:50 2014-18-11
```

How to get this , Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: What's the result you got with your attempts so far?

Comment: I get 02:20 2014-18-11 , but i need to show result like 20:50 2014-18-11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're able to include new libraries on your project, I'd highly recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) (MIT license) instead of writing this yourself. It solves problems like zero padding etc. for you.

Example

```
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Use an existing date object
var date = new Date("2014-11-18T20:50:01.462Z");
console.log(moment(date).format('HH:mm YYYY-DD-MM'));

// or use string directly
console.log(moment.utc("2014-11-18T20:50:01.462Z").format('HH:mm YYYY-DD-MM'));
</script>
```

Note by default moment will use your current timezone for output, this can be overridden using the zone() function

```
console.log(moment.utc("2014-11-18T20:50:01.462Z").zone(0).format('HH:mm YYYY-DD-MM'));
console.log(moment.utc("2014-11-18T20:50:01.462Z").zone('UTC+05:30').format('HH:mm YYYY-DD-MM'));
```

Output

```
20:50 2014-18-11
```

Comment: Thanks For your answer , I'm getting result like 02:20 2014-11-19 , Are u getting "20:50 2014-18-11" result ?

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: My time zone is GMT (IST - India Standard Time)

Comment: I think moment is automatically printing out the UTC time in IST which is +5:30, try the zone(0) example I've added to my answer....

Answer (score 1):

Try moment js its very nice plugin to play around dates and times

so all you need to do is import moment js and put this line in your js code 
using moment.js will also help you in future for your code

```
moment.utc("2014-11-18T20:50:01.462Z").format("HH:mm YYYY-DD-MM")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.prototype._padding = function(v, w) {
    var f = "0000" + v;
    return ("0000" + v).substr(f.length-w, f.length)
}

Date.prototype.MyDateString = function() {
    return this._padding(this.getUTCHours(), 2) + ":" + this._padding(this.getUTCMinutes(), 2) + " " + this.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + this._padding(this.getUTCDate(), 2) + "-" + this._padding((this.getUTCMonth() + 1), 2);

}
console.log(new Date('2014-11-18T20:50:01.462Z').MyDateString())
console.log(new Date('2014-11-08T02:05:01.462Z').MyDateString())
```

`getUTCMonth` return 10, as the month is 0 based.

Comment: This could lead to outputs like 1:1 2014-25-12 because it does not zero pad minutes

Answer (score 0):

Use this **[Demo JsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/mthdA/481/)**

```
 var d = new Date,
        dformat = [ d.getHours().padLeft(), d.getMinutes().padLeft()].join(':')
                      + ' ' +
                  [d.getFullYear(), d.getDate().padLeft(), (d.getMonth()+1).padLeft()].join('-')
                  ;
```